# Splitting data based on time(hour) efficiently

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is essentially group amounts of "votes" in relation to the hours of the day for the current day.

Say I have data like this:

```
$array = array(
    array('vote' => 'up', 'timestamp' => '1460514600'),    //10.30am
    array('vote' => 'up', 'timestamp' => '1460514600'),    //10.30am
    array('vote' => 'down', 'timestamp' => '1460514600'),  //10.30am
    array('vote' => 'up', 'timestamp' => '1460514600'),    //10.30am
    array('vote' => 'down', 'timestamp' => '1460514600'),  //10.30am
    array('vote' => 'up', 'timestamp' => '1460529000'),    //2.30pm
    array('vote' => 'up', 'timestamp' => '1460529000'),    //2.30pm
    array('vote' => 'down', 'timestamp' => '1460529000'),  //2.30pm
);
```

I currently have the following to section it into 24-hour based hours:

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $element){
    $hour = date('H', $element['timestamp']);
    if(!isset($new[$hour])){
        $new[$hour] = array(
            'up' => 0,
            'down' => 0,
        );
    }
    // check & add
    switch($element['vote']){
        case "up":
            $new[$hour]['up']++;
            break;
        case "down":
            $new[$hour]['down']++;
            break;
    }

}
```

Which returns the data as desired:

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [up] => 3
            [down] => 2
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [up] => 2
            [down] => 1
        )

)
```

---

**Is there a more efficient way of doing this sectioning? Even if it's possible to do it directly from Mysql?**

Comment: Looks pretty good for me

Comment: probably all doable in the querry

Comment: @Dagon - was thinking about that but wouldn't it be expensive? (*many many records*)

Comment: @RyanVincent - The query fetching the data only fetches it for the current day so it's safe in that aspect :)

Comment: This is fine, I wouldn't be trying to optimize this unless you had a problem where a benchmark was showing it as an issue.

Comment: some kind of aggregate\group by - not my area, if this works, then just move on

Comment: you mean something like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d55485c/1

Comment: @Darren I don't think you can optimize this code much, you can just write it differently: https://3v4l.org/fJRYv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sql guru here, but the closest that I can come up is to just use a simple `SUM` and `CASE` to count up all the vote ups and downs with a `GROUP BY` on the formatted hour (if it is indeed saved as a unix timestamp).

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`), '%H')
    AS group_hour,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_up,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'down' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_down
FROM table_name

GROUP BY `group_hour`
```

[<sup>Somewhat of a demo</sup>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d55485c/1)

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I'm looking for! Cheers Ghost

Comment: @Darren sure bro glad this helped